# Is there a quick and easy way to switch Tor on/off in Chrome and other browsers?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari, tor

Recently I was playing around with the Tor Browser. It is quite slow though, so it got me thinking that perhaps there is a better way to use Tor. I attempted to follow instructions on a few websites to get other browsers to use Tor, but these instructions are either outdated or incorrect. This is a two part question really:

1. Is there an easy way to get my other web browsers to utilize Tor in an on/off mechanism type of way? I don't want to permanently use them for Tor browsing.
2. Is there a way to speed up web browsing on the Tor network? It seems horribly slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. TOR integration for [Firefox](https://www.torproject.org/torbutton/), for [Safari](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en), and for [Opera](http://operator.en.softonic.com/).
2. Simple answer, no.  Browsing will be slow because you are going through random TOR routers.  It's the price of the extra layer of security.